# VBScript consumes memory after Creators Update (Win 10, 64bit)

Tags: memory, vbscript, com, windows-10

Since the latest Windows update (creators-update, `winver` gives 1703, build 15063.483) we have problems with VBScript accessing COM objects. It just seems to consume memory until memory exceeds.

We already have checked our sources and made it to just one simple vbs file that uses the `FileSystemObject`.

Look at this simple script file:

```vb
Dim fso, folder

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso Is Nothing Then
    Do
        Set folder = Nothing
        Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users")
    Loop 
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End If
```

It does just nothing but hanging in that loop, but if O look at the Task Manager I see the process `wscript.exe` consuming memory.

This doen only happen on Windows 10 systems with the creators update installed.

Any hints whats going wrong? Maybe a bug anywhere in the VBScript engine?

Comment: It should because you aren't pausing script a bit. You should use `sleep` statements. Are you sure you didn't use `sleep` statements even before the update and above consumed less memory?

Comment: no, it doesnt has to do with sleep-statements. before creators update the script "works", which means it does not consume any further memory when its running. yes, i am sure on that. can test the script parallel at two systems, one with the update, one without (and of course its just for testing and has not much to do with our real app which has the same problem)

Comment: On the system on which this does not work, what is the memory consumption pattern?Like does it gets to a very large value from starting itself or grows gradually?

Comment: it grows constantly until the process crashes due to out-of-memory. its not specific to the filesystemobject oder the get-folder-method. looks like any com-method calls from vbs leads to the problem

Comment: It seems there is an issue with the creators update.Some of the other side effects(like broken cmd) have been reported on microsoft forums.A lot of times updating solved the issue.See if you have new updates,or reinstall this update.

Comment: its a clean, fresh installed windows-system with defender and firewall deactivated and no additional anti-virus software installed... and it has nothing to do with fso. other objects have the bug as well

Comment: Tested vbscript and javascript, both show the described behaviour, so it is not the VBScript engine. To exclude the host I've changed from `[w|c]script.exe` script to `.hta` file and the exposed behaviour does not happen neither in vbs nor in js. It *"seems"* a problem in the `[w|c]script.exe` code.

Comment: so whats the right way to contact MS about that?

Comment: How did this ever work, you don't break the loop its infinite without any offloading to the OS?? This will just loop and loop and loop until all your RAM is consumed. Its the classic mistake every VBScript dev makes, forgetting to break out of the loop, i've done it myself many times in the past.

Comment: Its just an example. Of course it just loops and loops and the script does not make any sense but it shows he problem: of course looping and accessing com-method must NOT more consume memory in every iteration. But it does since creators update. Try it by yourself: just get any com-object and call a simple getter from it. You have to do it in a loop to see the memory consumption. By now Microsoft has confirmed its a Bug

Comment: It doesn't show the problem, because an infinite loop in VBScript will produce a memory leak anyway, regardless of a COM issue. You need to [edit] the question with a better [mcve] that we can test.

Comment: Also, *"By now Microsoft has confirmed its a Bug"* - can you provide a reference to this?

Comment: "an infinite loop in VBScript will produce a memory leak anyway," - How come you think so? There is no memory allocation inside the loop. Just try it out: write some infinite-loop in a vbs-file and watch it in the taskmanager. The process might hang but it does not consume more memory at each iteration. - "can you provide a reference to this?" No I couldn't because its an email-conversation

Comment: One for [@eric-lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) perhaps...

Comment: I haven't worked at Microsoft since 2012 and I haven't worked on VBScript since 2001; I haven't the least idea what is wrong here, sorry.

Comment: @suriel: The way to contact Microsoft would be through [Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/). Last I knew they'd charge you up front for a development support case but would refund it if it turned out to be confirmed to be from a Microsoft bug. That was a long time ago, but it wouldn't surprise me if things still worked the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Version 1703 (OS Build 16241.1001) obtained via Windows Insider Program - Fast Ring. I assume this will eventually be rolled out in a generally available build.

Comment: I couldn't find any single patch doing this but a complete Win10-Image. I tried it out and - wow, it seems to work really. Thank you very much. Can you please tell me where you have that information from or where i can find something like that by myself? Do you know if this one will be rolled out via Windows-Update or as a single Patch?

Comment: I had a similar problem to yours and just thought I'd try the latest Windows 10 build I could find to see if was fixed.  I have since searched the MS Knowledge base and came across [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032188/windows-10-update-kb4032188](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032188/windows-10-update-kb4032188). I am going to rollback to build 15063 and give that a try. It has changes to jscript and vbscript dll files. I et you know the result.

Comment: Sadly KB4032188, the latest generally available cumulative update for Windows 10 Creators Update, does **NOT** fix this issue.  I also noted that the Windows Insider preview version is an evaluation licence with an expiry date so not really a viable solution :(

Answer (score 2):

Finally Microsoft have a solution in a general release of Windows 10. 
The [Windows 10 Fall Creators Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4028685/windows-10-get-the-fall-creators-update) (OS Version 1709 Build 16299.15) is now available and fixes this issue.