# BUG in last Windows 10 update

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

In the last Windows 10 I found a bug in File System Object (FSO) on Visual Basic Script (VBS).

Even if I closed a file, memory is not released.

If you read a file in a loop for monitor a log file, memory consuption is grow to infinite.

In Windows 7 and older Windows 10 SO this problem not exist.

Example:

```
path = "d:\LocalData\ps05448\Desktop\Prueba.txt"
Const FOR_READING = 1

pausado = 0

'Paramos todo por las siguientes razones.

Do Until pausado = 1
    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set file = oFso.OpenTextFile(path, FOR_READING)
    Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
        linea = file.ReadLine
        If InStr(linea, "Linea de salida") > 0 Then
            'WriteLog "No conecta con servidor", 0
            pausado = 1
        End If
    Loop
    file.Close
    Set file = Nothing
    Set oFso = Nothing
Loop
```

`Prueba.txt` its a plain text file without the exit text.

Comment: If it's a bug there's nothing we can do about it here. [Use the Feedback app](http://www.techulator.com/resources/13419-How-to-report-Windows-10-bugs-to-Microsoft.aspx) to report it to Microsoft (after checking [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10/) to see if the problem has already been addressed).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274885/vbscript-consumes-memory-after-creators-update-win-10-64bit